# How do date formats work across SSIS, SQL, and all of the variable settings?

Tags: ssis

I am learning the basics of SSIS. I simply want to poke my database (MS SQL) and ask it for some dates stored in it. I don't particularly care about times, just dates (eg. `2019-09-06`). I would like to ask my database for dates relative to the current one. Something along the lines of `SELECT TOP 1 dateColumn FROM tableName WHERE dateColumn > GETDATE()`. I would then like to store the results from `dateColumn` into an SSIS variable, in order to make use of them later. I cannot seem to populate the variables, they just stay with the value SSIS assigns them when I created them.

What I don't understand is what datatypes everything needs to be set to.

In my database, should the column be `date` or `datetime`? In SSIS should the variables be `DateTime`? Something else?

Thanks

ETA: I am running these queries inside of 'Execute SQL Task' blocks in the Control Flow

Comment: Please check data type mapping [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/integration-services-data-types?view=sql-server-2017#mapping-of-integration-services-data-types-to-database-data-types).

In execute sql task parameter mapping assure that the data type is DT_DBTIMESTAMP.

Comment: @JIKEN Thank you very much, I don't know how I missed that.

Comment: @JIKEN Do you know how this relates to the variables page? In that view I can only assign things as "DateTime", and assign nothing as `DT_*`.  And where in the SQL task should I set the DT_DBTIMESTAMP? I don't see that option in the results set page.

Comment: DBTIMESTAMP - This Output parameter type is available to set datetime value to variable. Check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/parameters-and-return-codes-in-the-execute-sql-task?view=sql-server-2014#using-date-and-time-parameters-with-ole-db-connection-managers)

Comment: @JIKEN Thank you. I now understand that I can export a value from a module as such. What type of persistent variable (of the type User::VariableName) would be appropriate for this? [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/integration-services-ssis-variables?view=sql-server-2017)